# bash: complex test in find command

Tags: linux, bash, find

I would like to do something like:

```
find . -type f -exec test $(file --brief --mime-type '{}' ) == 'text/html' \; -print
```

but I can't figure out the correct way to quote or escape the args to test, especially the '$(' ... ')' .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot simply escape the arguments for passing them to `find`.

Any shell expansion will happen *before* `find` is run. `find` will not pass its arguments through a shell, so even if you escape the shell expansion, everything will simply be treated as literal arguments to the `test` command, not expanded by the shell as you are expecting.

The best way to achieve what you want would be to write a short shell script, which takes the filename as an argument, and use `-exec` on that:

```
find . -type f -exec is_html.sh {} \; -print
```

with `is_html.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

test $(file --brief --mime-type "$1") == 'text/html'
```

If you really want it all on one line, without using a separate script, you can invoke `sh` directly from `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'test $(file --brief --mime-type "$0") == "text/html"' {} \; -print
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer! I'm trying to avoid having to create a seperate command script just for the test. This seems to work as well:  `find . -type f -exec file --mime-type '{}' \; | grep 'text/html' | cut -d':' -f1` , but I was hoping for a more general solution to this kind of pattern.

Comment: You can also use the -c option of bash instead of writing the code in a separate file: find . -type f -exec bash -c 'test $(file --brief --mime-type "$1") == "text/html"' '' {} \; -print

Comment: @Bart yes, you can put it all inline by invoking `bash` or `sh` directly; I thought that it would be clearer to use a separate file, but you're right, if you really want to put it all on one line, you can do that.

Comment: If you're worried about spaces in the result of `file`, this worked for me:
`find . -type f -exec sh -c 'test "$(file --brief --mime-type "$0")" == "text/html"' {} \; -print

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be possible to turn it into one wildly quoted statement, it is often easier - and more clear - to be a little more verbose:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file --mime-type | ↷
   grep ':[^:]*text/html$'| sed 's,:[^:]*text/html,,'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "{}" instead, for an example this simply lists file types:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -exec file "{}" \;
```